# Elasticsearch Compounded Words

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, elastica

we're using elasticsearch with seperate index for each language.

This is our config for german analyzer:

```
settings:
    index:
        analysis:
            filter:
                nGramFilter:
                    type: nGram
                    min_gram: 2
                    max_gram: 4
            analyzer:
                de_analyzer:
                    tokenizer: standard
                    filter: [standard, lowercase, "nGramFilter"]
```

However, if I search for "apfel" (apple), it also finds "Apfelsine", which is not an apple. If I search for "wein" (wine), it also finds "Schweinshaxe", which is not correct.

We also tried the edgeNGram Filter, but it also doesn't fit our needs.

Has anyone an idea to accomplish this?

Comment: What type of matching do you need? e.g. exact matching with a lowercase?

Comment: There is a Elasticsearch plugin specifically written for compound words that you should try: https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-analysis-decompound

Comment: Thx, I'll take a look on the plugin.

@Olly We need exact matching and stuff like above. For example we've "Apfel" and "Apfelkuchen". Search for "Apfel" should result in both ...

Comment: The plugin looks really nice. Why it doesnt tokenize "steuer"? Anyway....I'm excited to try this out tomorrow. Thanks :)

Comment: What does your analyzer have to do with with the German language? That's just the standard analyzer with an ngram filter. Have you considered a [german language analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#german-analyzer) if I'm missing something about your config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Udan The plugin works like a charm. We'll use this in production env. Thanks very much.